# passing appender.file value in log4j.properties file at runtime

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to pass the path to create logs file in.

```
String logsPath="C:/";
   System.setProperty("logs", logsPath);
  log.debug("Debug");
  log.info("Info");
```

my `logs.properties` file looks like this:

```
log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.X.File=$(logs)/logs.log
```

problem:-the program is running just fine without any errors but the logs are not being printed.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason is that log4j is faster to initialize than `System.setProperty ("logs", logsPath);` line.
   Run Process with the following options:
   `-Dlogs="C:/"`
   Example:
   `java -Dlogs="C:/" MyClass`
2. Replace `$(logs)` with `${logs}`.

Comment: -D<property name>=<property value>

Comment: my requirement is to set path of 2 different loggers dynamically and the system.setproperty() command should be called from different methods.so,is there a way to do that??

Comment: log4j is initialized once and can not dynamically change the property. If you want to dynamically act on certain conditions, inherit and implement FileAppender. `log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.YourFileAppender`